# Example of a JDBC type 3 driver

Tags: java, jdbc, driver

I'm currently searching for a JDBC type 3 driver, but they seem to be very rare, as I couldn't find one. Does anyone know a type 3 driver?
And yes, I need an type 3 because an middle-ware server (a proxy application) has to analyse and log the incoming queries.

Comment: Why not just turn on query logging on the db?

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting what a Type 3 JDBC driver is for, and taking a random Type 3 driver will likely not do what you need. As suggested in your other questions, you'll need to write a custom JDBC driver to achieve what you want (and potentially that driver could be a type 3 driver, depending on your needs). As an aside, asking for off-site resources, like examples of JDBC type 3 drivers, is off-topic. I highly recommend that you take the [tour] and familiarize yourself with the rules and expectations of Stack Overflow through the [help].

Comment: @g00se because i want to manipulate the sql statements before sending it to the db